# Why I have same problem with telegram send by php?

Tags: php, wordpress, telegram

I get this problem when sending form

failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in /wp-content/themes/portfolio/telegram/telegram-processing.php on line 44

There is written this stroke on line 44

```php
$sendToTelegram = fopen("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id}&parse_mode=html&text={$txt}","r");
```

`token`, `id`, `txt` are right. Only this line do not work. Please say me where I have mistake.
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe there is an issue with the API call. Have you verified the construction of the call is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace your line with:

```
$sendToTelegram = sendMessage($chat_id,$txt,$token);
```

and add this function to your code:

```
function sendMessage($chat_id, $txt, $token) {
    echo "sending message to " . $chat_id. "\n";

    $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . $token . "/sendMessage?chat_id=" . $chat_id;
    $url = $url . "&text=" . urlencode($txt);
    $ch = curl_init();
    $optArray = array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
    );
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $optArray);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have already corrected the mistake. I have deleted this bot and create new bot with new id and token. Now it works.